# install mod_semantic_map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,i want to install mod_semantic_map
but i don't understand that it is not yet in our index.!!
what should i do about this ?! i can't understand

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46317/install-mod_semantic_map/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like [mod_semantic_map](http://ros.org/wiki/mod_semantic_map) isn't indexed properly on ros.org, but if you browse software on ros.org and go to its [details page](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=mod_semantic_map), you'll find that source is available [here](https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge/mod_semantic_map/) and a tutorial is available [here](http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Mod_semantic_map).

**EDIT:**
You should have a look at the [environment variables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) wiki page to understand what's happening with the failure of rosmake.

rosmake uses the variable **ROS_PACKAGE_PATH** when looking for ROS packages to compile.  If you create or download a new package and its directory isn't on the path, rosmake won't work.

To see what the path currently is, type 'echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'

If the directory in which you put mod_semantic_map isn't on that path, then you know that's the problem.

To add a directory to the path, type 'export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/the/directory/to/add:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'

You may also want to put this line in your ~/.bashrc file so it will happen automatically at login.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-10-19**:
It's a subversion repository, so you should type 'svn co [https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge/mod_semantic_map/'](https://tum-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge/mod_semantic_map/%27) in whatever folder you want to download the code. Then, you'll want to rosmake the package.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-10-20**:
BTW, mod_semantic_map depends on knowrob, so make sure you can "roscd knowrob" to knowrob stack first.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-10**:
this is when i do that tbh
http://www.mediafire.com/?90p7ll5wa63bq5u

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-10**:
@Ricky
Yes  i can "roscd knowrob "

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-12**:
@tbh
i did that in another package "Roboearth"
and didn't work too
see that please :
http://answers.ros.org/question/47981/errors-in-stacks-in-ros/

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-11-15**:
Please have a look at the first two ROS tutorials "Installing and Configuring Your ROS Environment" and "Navigating the ROS Filesystem" on this page http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials. Your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH needs to be correct for rosmake to find the packages.